# Delete object from javascript array using variable property value

Tags: javascript, arrays, slice, splice

Hi all pretty new to javascript and would love some help on this problem that Im having. Basically what I am trying to do is to delete a single object from my array. The array contains objects as such: `y = [{id:group}].`

I would like to delete an object using the object's id, which is the first column.

What I have tried is to loop through the array to find the corresponding id and delete it, but the problem here is that the first column is not labelled "id", the first column is in id form (e.g 123).

Any help would be appreciated.

```
y = [{123:1},{321:2},{234:3}]
id = 123;

  for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++)
    if (y[i].id === id) {
      y.splice(i,1);
    }
//Does not work because the first column of the object is not named "id"
```

Comment: Dynamic property names are great if you know what they're going to be, but you don't.  A more useful object structure would be `{id: 123, group: 1}`

Comment: @James Took your advice and decided to recreate my object structure. The  solutions here dont work anymore but the array is now easier to work with. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just check for that certain key:

```
for (var i = 0; i < y.length; i++)
  if (key in y[i]) {
    y.splice(i,1);
  }
}
```

Comment: I did go with your loop method in the end because performance was better and it made more sense to me even though the filter method looked cleaner. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) instead of a loop:

```js
var y = [{123:1},{321:2},{234:3}]
var id = 123;

y = y.filter((obj) => !obj.hasOwnProperty(id));

console.log(y);
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked really well. Could you tell me what is the benefit of using filter compared to using a loop?

Comment: @user 3702643 its syntactic sugar. Using loops is faster and does not recreate the array from the ground of...

Comment: The performance is roughly the same, and the code becomes more readable. Another advantage is the functional aspect of it, as you can assign the filtered array to another variable, not having side-effect

Answer (score 1):

I make a function using two arguments (the array, the key of the object)
Using forEach method inside the array I check and compare the the key given key (via argument) with an existen key in the object elements.If it is true then I use splice() method to remove the object contains the key:

```js
y = [{123:1},{321:2},{234:3}];

function deleteObj(arg,value){
  arg.forEach(function(element){       
    var index=arg.indexOf(element);    
    if(Object.keys(element)==value.toString()){
      arg.splice(index,1);
    }
  });
}
deleteObj(y,123);

console.log(y);
```